# Fetch user plotted latitude and longitude on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've a map displayed to the user, and he/she has the ability to plot on the map his/her location and the google map marker appears, now how do I fetch programatically the location plotted by the user on the google map. I will be using this data and storing it in my database, which I can handle on my own, but I'm unsure of how to fetch the data plotted by the user.

Someone has already implemented it or has a link or tutorials to it, please share.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3

Comment: How does the user have the ability to plot their location? Do you have any code at all to share?

Comment: User clicks on the map and a marker is displayed using the map click event.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using? drawingManager? For multiple markers I write mine to an array then to a hidden input field and loop through it to add to the database whatever way you want:

```
    var markerArray = new Array();
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'markercomplete', function(marker) {
        markerArray.push(marker.getPosition());
        document.divID.inputName.value = markerArray;
    });
```

and then remove markers from rightclick and splice it off the array.

Note: I write mine to a hidden input field as I do all my queries in php.

Comment: no I have a save button inside the infobox and once the infobox opens user enters data like name, age, etc and clicking on save submits to db using AJAX request.